# Making 50th Anniversary Invitations - Card Stock won't work in printer

Tags: adhesives

I'm trying to create my own 50th Anniversary invitations for my parents and I'm running into issues where my laser printer won't accept the card stock I got. It said it would, but I've tried and tried and it jam's every time.  SO....my option is to print out on regular paper then glue to the card stock. Question....how can I make the paper stick to the card stock without wrinkles? I read some of other posts and they said to use the spray adhesive glue.  Would that still be the ok and work great for this? I have 100 invitations I'm mailing out. The rest of invites are being done via Facebook, etc.

Comment: It might be easier (and look better) for you to see if your local print shop (FedEx office, etc) can print them for you. You've done the hard work (designing them)... if you give them the file and the paper, they should be able to print them in minutes rather than you spending hours gluing.

Comment: What about print on sticker paper? It's designed to be fed into a laser printer. And once printed pull off the stick and stick it to your heavier card stick paper. Could create some wonderful cut out effects.

Comment: Sorry if I am telling you something really elementary here, but did you adjust the settings on your laser printer for heavy stock? Depending on the printer, heavy stock might need to use the manual feed tray, and will definitely need to move through the system at a slower pace, so that there is enough time for the laser to heat-set the toner.  As long as the card stock is designed for laser printers, it should work pretty well once you have figured out the correct settings for your printer.

Comment: Check with your friends and coworkers to see if anyone you know owns a printer with a flat paper path.  They aren't that common, but Epson used to make a good inkjet that could print on printable cds as well as on paper.    That type of printer would have no difficulty printing on 40lb or 80lb card stock.

Answer (score 2):

A good scrapbooking adhesive tape, like Elmer's CraftBond Permanent Tape (http://www.elmers.com/product/detail/E4006) will provide strong adhesion without the mess and wrinkles of glue. I recently used it to stick regular paper into a sketchbook (with thick art paper pages), and it was great. No wrinkles, no mess, and very sticky.